# How can a retail trader work on improving his trade execution

Tags: brokerage, online-trading

In some trading books, the trader is advised to work on getting better execution. What does this really mean? For execution, the trader is at the mercy of the broker's algorithms and infrastructure.

Does the advice just mean to select a broker with good reputation of fills for market orders?

Comment: An industry trader would run an experiment on each exchange by sending a batch of orders through various brokers (varying the product, time of day, type of order, etc.) and comparing the resulting speed of execution, fill percentage, etc.  I suppose a retail trader could do that too, but it would get expensive (in time and money).

Comment: In these books does it not explain how to get better trade execution?

Comment: Read this to achieve [Flawless Trade Execution](http://www.tradingmarkets.com/recent/3_keys_to_flawless_execution-677561.html)

Comment: @Victor123 - why was the link awful? It actually provides details on improving ones trade execution as would be described in the trading books you write about. Maybe you should spend some time reading the books you didn't refer to, to get your answer!

Comment: It was awful because it sounded like those run of the mill trading advice that they blabber about on the news channel. Nothing against you, and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Victor123 - again have you actually read the explanation in the trading books you so called mentioned about improving trade execution, because it is nothing to do with the broker you choose and more to do with your actual execution of your trading. You need to concentrate on what is in your control to improve not what is out of your control.

Comment: It looks like @Victor123 has not read any books, must have just read the headline or statement somewhere, but doesn't really want to know what it's true meaning is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct market access and ways to get fills is the real answer.

The platform you use also dictates your execution.

The algorithm you use to get filled dictates this.

The algorithms on the exchanges themselves can hamper your execution.

Smart routing may get you access to the most liquidity, but "high frequency algorithms" (low latency fast execution) will ensure that you get worse fills

these are the factors to consider

Comment: IB offers DMA. Does all my trades automatically go through DMA? DMA is a very copnfusing area for me. How to actually avail of this feature?

Comment: If you are paying data fees you are likely using DMA. Whereas usually a broker-dealer pays these fees and charges all their customers the same (high) commissions rate. Also every single exchange has a large concoction of the kinds of orders they accept, which also changes by the kind of market you are trading. You can route an order to a specific exchange, if you want, or just use the smart routing feature to go to all of them (HFT only begins to matter when your partial fills start getting annoying to you)